# Call ngOnInit for specific component in angular

Tags: angular

I have function in `delete.component.ts` :

```
  onDelete() {
    //to delete data in server based on device id
    this.httpService.deleteDataFromServer(this.data.apiToSend).subscribe((resp) => {
      if(resp.status == 'SUCCESS'){
      location.reload() <---- HERE my goal
      }
    })
  }
```

I have multiple component like simcard :

```
deleteDevice(id){
  this.dialog.open(DeleteDevicePopupComponent, {
    data:{
      deviceType: 'SIM Card',
      apiToSend: 'api/simcard?id='+id
    }
  })
}
```

Everything fine when i click delete directly call this function and delete data everything fine...

My problem in i don't want to use `location.reload()` insted of this i want use this.ngOnInit() to reload in same component but i am in other component so how i can call ngOnInit() in other component?

Graph:  apply function delete ---> in body of function apply ngOnInit to component (simcard example).

I try to add `this.ngOnInit()` directly in same component `(simcard not delete.component)` here :

```
  deleteDevice(id){
    this.dialog.open(DeleteDevicePopupComponent, {
      data:{
        deviceType: 'Camera',
        apiToSend: 'api/dash_cam_device?id='+id
      },
    })
    this.ngOnInit();
  }
```

But not work!

Comment: the onInit method isn't a method that you call, it's a life cycle hook that angular calls internally.

Comment: i know we can use it to reload data in same component, my goal is general how to call any method from other component. @tcrite

Answer (score 0):

take a look at

ComponentRef from '@angular/core';

I thnik you could achive this with it

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in the `ngOninit()` in to another method and call it from `ngOninit()`

```
ngOninit(){
this.yourMethod();
}
```

and from another component emit an event when a desired action is performed and catch the event in the parent component and call the custom method()

Comment: a simple example to understand how... @Midhun Gopinath